# Fortran - want to round to one decimal point

Tags: fortran, rounding, gfortran, netcdf

In fortran I have to round latitude and longitude to one digit after decimal point.

I am using gfortran compiler and the nint function but the following does not work:

```
print *, nint( 1.40 * 10. ) / 10.    ! prints 1.39999998
print *, nint( 1.49 * 10. ) / 10.    ! prints 1.50000000
```

Looking for both general and specific solutions here.  For example:

1. How can we display numbers rounded to one decimal place?
2. How can we store such rounded numbers in fortran.  It's not possible in a float variable, but are there other ways?
3. How can we write such numbers to NetCDF?
4. How can we write such numbers to a CSV or text file?

Comment: The really short answer is that you can't do this. Floating point representation is inexact and there is no guarantees that the floating point division by ten (or rounded to one decimal) has exact representation at whatever size floating point type you are using. Is this only for printing or display?

Comment: @talonmies - no it is not printing or display. I have an input netcdf file that has only one digit after decimal point. I have modified the longitude and I want to write it back to a netcdf file.

Comment: Well, you can't do this with floating point. You will need to use a fixed point or decimal type instead

Comment: @talonmies - can you show an example and add that as an answer ? I will be happy to upvote and accept

Comment: What  format is the value to be stored in within the netCDF file?

Comment: @talonmies - my ncdump says the lat and lon are stored as floats. That is just like 52.0 or 52.5 or 40.5 etc.

Comment: NetCDF float is the same as Fortran REAL.

Comment: @JohnE It is perfectly fine. Please feel free to edit as you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do what you are asking. The underlying problem is that the rounded values you desire are not necessarily able to be represented using floating point.

For example, if you had a value 10.58, this is represented exactly as 1.3225000 x 2^3 = 10.580000 in IEEE754 float32.

When you round this to value to one decimal point (however you choose to do so), the result would be 10.6, however 10.6 does not have an exact representation. The nearest representation is 1.3249999 x 2^3 = 10.599999 in float32. So no matter how you deal with the rounding, there is no way to store 10.6 exactly in a float32 value, and no way to write it as a floating point value into a netCDF file.

Comment: It depends upon what "writing it back to the file" means. If it is with a FORMAT(F6.1,....) then it would work.

Comment: @Holmz: note I wrote [*netCDF file*](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/data_type.html)

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, the issue is the use of floating point representation in the NetCDF file. Using `nco` utilities, you can change the latitude/longitude to short integers with scale_factor and add_offset. Like this:

```
ncap2 -s 'latitude=pack(latitude, 0.1, 0); longitude=pack(longitude, 0.1, 0);' old.nc new.nc
```

Comment: @JohnE If you're looking to "print a number rounded number or write it to a CSV" what's wrong with `write(*,'(f1.1)') 1.40` and `write(*,'(f1.1)') 1.49`? The whole point of the answers to the OP's question is that NetCDF has very specific allowed formats, and truncated floating-point isn't allowed.

Comment: @JohnE imho, if anything needs doing then the question (and in particular the title) should be edited to make the NetCDF requirement clear and hopefully send the search traffic to a more relevant information source. I believe it's possible to have a bounty removed by a mod if you think you've bountied the wrong question.

Comment: @JohnE I am happy to remove the answer if it confuses things. However, I only saw this question because of the netcdf tag on it.

Comment: @RobertDavy  No, please leave it.  I'll probably give the bounty to a different answer based on what I was looking for, but you have 2 upvotes as I type this, so obviously there are others who find this helpful.  More answers means more options for people, this is good.

Answer (score 3):

YES, IT CAN BE DONE!  The "accepted" answer above is correct in its limited range, but is wrong about what you can actually accomplish in Fortran (or various other HGL's).

The only question is what price are you willing to pay, if the something like a Write with F(6.1) fails?

From one perspective, your problem is a particularly trivial variation on the subject of "Arbitrary Precision" computing.  How do you imagine cryptography is handled when you need to store, manipulate, and perform "math" with, say, 1024 bit numbers, with exact precision?

A simple strategy in this case would be to separate each number into its constituent "LHSofD" (Left Hand Side of Decimal), and "RHSofD" values.  For example, you might have an RLon(i,j) = 105.591, and would like to print 105.6 (or any manner of rounding) to your netCDF (or any normal) file.  Split this into RLonLHS(i,j) = 105, and RLonRHS(i,j) = 591.

... at this point you have choices that increase generality, but at some expense.  To save "money" the RHS might be retained as 0.591 (but loose generality if you need to do fancier things).

For simplicity, assume the "cheap and cheerful" second strategy.

The LHS is easy (Int()).

Now, for the RHS, multiply by 10 (if, you wish to round to 1 DEC), e.g. to arrive at RLonRHS(i,j) = 5.91, and then apply Fortran "round to nearest Int" NInt() intrinsic ... leaving you with RLonRHS(i,j) = 6.0.

... and Bob's your uncle:

Now you print the LHS and RHS to your netCDF using a suitable Write statement concatenating the "duals", and will created an EXACT representation as per the required objectives in the OP.

... of course later reading-in those values returns to the same issues as illustrated above, unless the read-in also is ArbPrec aware.

... we wrote our own ArbPrec lib, but there are several about, also in VBA and other HGL's ... but be warned a full ArbPrec bit of machinery is a non-trivial matter ... lucky you problem is so simple.

Answer (score 3):

The `round_x = nint(x*10d0)/10d0' operator rounds x (for abs(x) < 2**31/10, for large numbers use dnint()) and assigns the rounded value to the round_x variable for further calculations.

As mentioned in the answers above, not all numbers with one significant digit after the decimal point have an exact representation, for example, 0.3 does not.

```
print *, 0.3d0
```

Output:

```
  0.29999999999999999
```

To output a rounded value to a file, to the screen, or to convert it to a string with a single significant digit after the decimal point, use edit descriptor 'Fw.1' (w - width w characters, 0 - variable width). For example:

```
print '(5(1x, f0.1))', 1.30, 1.31, 1.35, 1.39, 345.46
```

Output:

```
 1.3 1.3 1.4 1.4 345.5
```

@JohnE, using 'G10.2' is incorrect, it rounds the result to two significant digits, not to one digit after the decimal point. Eg:

```
print '(g10.2)',  345.46
```

Output:

> 0.35E+03

P.S.

For NetCDF, rounding should be handled by NetCDF viewer, however, you can output variables as NC_STRING type:

```
write(NetCDF_out_string, '(F0.1)') 1.49
```

Or, alternatively, get "beautiful" NC_FLOAT/NC_DOUBLE numbers:

```
beautiful_float_x = nint(x*10.)/10. + epsilon(1.)*nint(x*10.)/10./2.
beautiful_double_x = dnint(x*10d0)/10d0 + epsilon(1d0)*dnint(x*10d0)/10d0/2d0
```

P.P.S. @JohnE

0. The preferred solution is not to round intermediate results in memory or in files. Rounding is performed only when the final output of human-readable data is issued;
1. Use print with edit descriptor ‘Fw.1’, see above;
2. There are no simple and reliable ways to accurately store rounded numbers (numbers with a decimal fixed point):

2.1. Theoretically, some Fortran implementations can support decimal arithmetic, but I am not aware of implementations that in which ‘selected_real_kind(4, 4, 10)’ returns a value other than -5;

2.2. It is possible to store rounded numbers as strings;

2.3. You can use the Fortran binding of GIMP library. Functions with the mpq_ prefix are designed to work with rational numbers;

3. There are no simple and reliable ways to write rounded numbers in a netCDF file while preserving their properties for the reader of this file:

3.1. netCDF supports 'Packed Data Values‘, i.e. you can set an integer type with the attributes’ scale_factor‘,’ add_offset' and save arrays of integers. But, in the file ‘scale_factor’ will be stored as a floating number of single or double precision, i.e. the value will differ from 0.1. Accordingly, when reading, when calculating by the netCDF library `unpacked_data_value = packed_data_value*scale_factor + add_offset`, there will be a rounding error. (You can set `scale_factor=0.1*(1.+epsilon(1.))` or `scale_factor=0.1d0*(1d0+epsilon(1d0))` to exclude a large number of digits '9'.);

3.2. There are C_format and FORTRAN_format attributes. But it is quite difficult to predict which reader will use which attribute and whether they will use them at all;

3.3. You can store rounded numbers as strings or user-defined types;

4. Use write() with edit descriptor ‘Fw.1’, see above.

Comment: @JohnE, It seems to me that your changing the question still doesn't improve it.

Answer (score 3):

There are several aspects one can consider in relation to "rounding to one decimal place". These relate to: internal storage and manipulation; display and interchange.

### Display and interchange

The simplest aspects cover how we report stored value, regardless of the internal representation used.  As covered in depth in other answers and elsewhere we can use a numeric edit descriptor with a single fractional digit:

```
print '(F0.1,2X,F0.1)', 10.3, 10.17
end
```

How the output is rounded is a *changeable mode*:

```
print '(RU,F0.1,2X,RD,F0.1)', 10.17, 10.17
end
```

In this example we've chosen to round up and then down, but we could also round to zero or round to nearest (or let the compiler choose for us).

For any formatted output, whether to screen or file, such edit descriptors are available. A `G` edit descriptor, such as one may use to write CSV files, will also do this rounding.

For unformatted output this concept of rounding is not applicable as the internal representation is referenced. Equally for an interchange format such as NetCDF and HDF5 we do not have this rounding.

For NetCDF your attribute convention may specify something like `FORTRAN_format` which gives an appropriate format for ultimate display of the (default) real, non-rounded, variable .

### Internal storage

Other answers and the question itself mention the impossibility of accurately representing (and working with) decimal digits. However, nothing in the Fortran language requires this to be impossible:

```
integer, parameter :: rk = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(radix=10)
real(rk) x
x = 0.1_rk

print *, x

end
```

is a Fortran program which has a radix-10 variable and literal constant. See also `IEEE_SELECTED_REAL_KIND(radix=10)`.

Now, you are exceptionally likely to see that `selected_real_kind(radix=10)` gives you the value `-5`, but if you want something positive that can be used as a type parameter you just need to find someone offering you such a system.

If you aren't able to find such a thing then you will need to work accounting for errors.  There are two parts to consider here.

The intrinsic real numerical types in Fortran are floating point ones. To use a fixed point numeric type, or a system like binary-coded decimal, you will need to resort to non-intrinsic types. Such a topic is beyond the scope of this answer, but pointers are made in that direction by DrOli.

These efforts will not be computationally/programmer-time cheap. You will also need to take care of managing these types in your output and interchange.

Depending on the requirements of your work, you may find simply scaling by (powers of) ten and working on integers suits. In such cases, you will also want to find the corresponding NetCDF attribute in your convention, such as `scale_factor`.

Relating to our internal representation concerns we have similar rounding issues to output.  For example, if my input data has a longitude of `10.17...` but I want to round it in my internal representation to (the nearest representable value to) a single decimal digit (say `10.2`/`10.1999998`) and then work through with that, how do I manage that?

We've seen how `nint(10.17*10)/10.` gives us this, but we've also learned something about how numeric edit descriptors do this nicely for output, including controlling the rounding mode:

```
character(10) :: intermediate
real :: rounded
write(intermediate, '(RN,F0.1)') 10.17
read(intermediate, *) rounded

print *, rounded  ! This may look not "exact"

end
```

We can track the accumulation of errors here if this is desired.